# Using html function outside component returning [object Object] LitElement

Tags: javascript, polymer, lit-element, lit

I'm having headaches with this, if someone knows how to solve it, will be awesome.
I'm using LitElement to create a table component, the developer that wants to use it can add a customHTML to render a different input.
To do it, he/she can use the property "headers", like this:

```
[{
  label: 'Created at',
  customHTML: (value, isEditable) => html`<custom-element .value="${value} .isEditable="${valueisEditable}"></custom-element>`
}]
```

Using inside component:

```
<td>${header.customHTML()}</td>
```

The problem that I'm facing is when I try to use this customHTML inside my table component, it is returning [object Object]. Have you any explanation for this? It is possible to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I sent the html method into the call customHTML: <td>${header.customHTML(html)}</td>

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are **using many versions of lit-element**.

Type in chrome console `window.litElementVersions` and you will see which versions of lit element you are using.

If you mix up the `html` tag from different imports from different versions, you will get `[object Object]`.

## The solution

There is no magic or much to do here. **Install all packages again**

```sh
rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock package-lock.json
npm i
# or
yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` is the default representation of an object converted to a string.

```js
const house = {
  windows: 4,
  height: 5
}

console.log(house.toString());
```

The custom html element is an object that you are refering to inside the `<td>` tag which is probably trying to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much code to really understand the problem but try to use `JSON.stringify(customHTML)`.

as string it will be more flexible to be printed as text.